# jQuery - on submit post to ajax, data is null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code here:

```
$('#q-form').submit(function(){
    $('.form-wrapper').hide();
    $('#cover').hide();

    var values = {};
    $.each($('#myForm').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: values,
        success: function(){
            $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

What I am trying to do is send the data from the form onsubmit to mail.php when I print_r $_POST in php its empty...why?

Comment: Does the "myForm" exist as an ID for an element in the form? I'd also wonder if the notation on that each line is correct to call the function on everything.

Comment: Are you using ChromeDev tools or some browser dev tools to see what request headers are actually being sent?

Comment: Isn't your loop equivalent to `values = $("#myForm").serialize();`?

Comment: What do you see if you add `console.log(values);`?